# PHP + User Edit Button

Tags: php

Sorry for my ignorance.  Does anyone have any input to help me here.

I'm trying to create a page that queries a database and shows open entries.  I want the users to be able to click inline, or by a seperate page and edit the field.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("maint", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Maintenance WHERE status='open'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<center><div style='top: 10px; left: 3px; width: 500px; height: 250px; border: dotted; padding: 5px'>";
echo "<br><b>Name: </b> " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
echo "<b>Issue: </b> " . $row['detailed'] . "<br>";
echo "<b>Status: </b>" . $row['status'] . "<br>";
echo "<b>Comments: </b>" . $row['comments'] . "<br>";
echo "<br/><br/>";
echo "<input type='submit' name=button /><br>";
echo "</div><br>";

}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Can someone just lead me in the correct direction.  I'm only a noob programmer so I apologize if this is basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the unique identifier of the current row while going through your `while` loop.
2. Make a form and place the button code inside of the form
3. Make a hidden field, whose value is the unique identifier of the current row
4. POST all data (either back to the current page, or a new one)
5. This part is all up to you now

For example, you may want to create a row of text boxes, their default values being the values of the echoed off rows. From there the user will be able to hit another button, "save", for example, which will then POST back the updated values along with the row's unique identifier. From here, simply query the database with the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to query it out in the database

```
select * from table where id=$userid
```

then echo it out on the html form something like this

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($post['name']))?>"/>
```